# Cannot view response data for AJAX requests made from Flex object in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: apache-flex, google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-devtools

I don't know exactly when this changed but probably around version 18...
In the past when a flash app (SWF) would make an AJAX call i can see the call logged and the response (which would be JSON) would be available in both the preview and response sub-tabs of the Network tab - mind you the response **would not** be pretty-printed tree in the preview tab.

Now, I see the AJAX calls and all the header info, but the Preview and Response sub-tabs are empty!

Is there a flag/setting that would log these? (I'm on Chrome 20)

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? Im facing the same problem.